# Algolia autocomplete search box doesn't show up in laravel

Tags: autocomplete, algolia

I followed [the documantation](https://stackoverflow.com):

`npm install @algolia/autocomplete-js`

`npm install @algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic`

shop.blade.php:

```
...
<div id="autocomplete"></div>
<script type="module">
    import { autocomplete } from './@algolia/autocomplete-js';
    import './@algolia/autocomplete-theme-classic';

    autocomplete({
        container: '#autocomplete',
        placeholder: 'Search for products',
        getSources() {
            return [];
        },
    });
</script>
```

When I open the page, there's not any box for searching, only `<div id="autocomplete"></div>` that's empty.

Please tell me what is wrong Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any errors in your browser developer console -- for instance, can you confirm  the library loading?

I was able to build up an autocomplete box using this blog, but I'm using vanilla Javascript, not `<script>` modules. I can confirm, that if the code executes, you should at least see a search button/box with that code, even though there aren't any sources wired to the search box.

https://www.algolia.com/blog/ux/replicating-the-algolia-documentation-search-with-autocomplete/

Comment: Thank you, no I don't get any errors in console, I'm not sure about loading. I used `cdn` for loading the library instead of `npm` and it worked,  what do you mean by using vanilla javascript and not script module? Blog says we need to put `import { autocomplete } from '@algolia/autocomplete-js';` in our javascript so the script should be module type.